# Mysql - using a conditional and alias

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting tables dynamically in PHP. Most of the tables have the field 'title'. But two of them are instead using the field 'name'. So what I am hoping is I can change the below statement to make 'name' alias to title if the field 'name' is found.

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT title FROM $place WHERE id=‘$id' ");
```

Comment: This kind of problem is highly suggestive of poor design!

Comment: You can't say that from one line of code

Answer (score 0):

you can use alias some like this:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT {$table}.title FROM $place as {$table} WHERE id=‘$id' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Just create views in the database for the two tables that have `name` instead of title:

```
create view v_table1 as
    select name as title, . . .
    from table1;
```

Then you can use the views and not have to do strange things on the application side.

Now.  Why you would want to do this is quite unclear.  If you have tables with common titles, then perhaps you should have a `Titles` table with foreign key references to that table.

Comment: The separate tables don't share the same title entries